# How to achieve logical OR in an Istio VirtualService regex?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

### The problem

The pipe character does not seem to work in Istio's `VirtualService`.

The example below is intended to route requests based on the `user-agent` header. Requests from a mobile device should go to `myapp` and requests from a desktop user should go to `deskt-app`, handled by next match block. The `<REGEX>` field works when I use this regex:

- `^.*\bMobile\b.*$`

But the powers that be require a more sophisticated regex to identify mobile users. My routing breaks entirely when I use these:

- `^.*\b(iPhone|Pixel)\b.*$`
- `^.*\b(iPhone|Pixel)+\b.*$`
- `^.*\biPhone|Pixel\b.*$`

### Expected behavior

Using a regex with a pipe (logical OR) I expect to be routed to `myapp` when I have a `user-agent` header that contains the word "iPhone" or "Pixel".

### Actual behavior

I get routed to `deskt-app`.

### The question

How do I achieve a logical OR in an Istio `VirtualService` regex pattern? And is that my problem or am I overlooking something obvious?

---

### Example `VirtualService`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
  ...
  ...
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        user-agent:
          regex: "<REGEX>"    <------
      uri:
        prefix: /foo/bar
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /foo/bar
    route:
    - destination:
        host: deskt-app
        port:
          number: 80
```

---

EDIT: [Github Issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10766)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is correct, so the issue must be with the Regex, or the contents of the user-agent are different, give this a try `'^.*(iPhone|Pixel).*$'`

Just verified that the configuration below routes correctly when the header contains android or iphone:

```
  - match:
    - headers: 
        user-agent: 
            regex: '^.*(Android|iPhone).*$'
```

And tested with:

**[match]** curl -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; iPhone 4.4.2; en-us;)" ...

**[no match]** curl -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Iphne 4.4.2; en-us;)" ...

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I will give this a try when I have a chance today.

Comment: Unfortunately the project was nixed before I could verify this.

Comment: Thanks @rinormaloku ! This worked perfectly fine.I tested this with Firefox user-agent switcher as well as real device...It works.